# How can I pause growl notifications via Terminal/Shell?

Tags: command-line, terminal, applescript, growl

I was wondering if there was a way I could pause (hide) growl notifications from the command line? Failing that, is there a way to do this with an AppleScript?

Answer (score 0):

The following *should* work with support for assistive devices enabled, unfortunately, it doesn't for me. But on my machine, even the regular menu  item fails to stop Growl…

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    set current pane to pane id "com.growl.prefpanel"
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "System Preferences"
            tell window "Growl"
                click radio button "General" of tab group 1
                click button "Stop Growl" of tab group 1
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
    quit
end tell
```